# API centric development in Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, api, zend-framework

I am trying to create an API centric webservice using Zend framework. I would like to have the front-end separated from the back-end and all communication should take place using the API only, as shown in this image:

[image]

The overall architecture can be summarized as shown in the following image:

[image]

I would like to know what is the best approach/ practice in terms of project organization and folder structure preferably keeping it compatible with zend's way of project organization.

Should I create two separate projects one for handling only the front-end while the other to act solely as the API server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a separate Zend Application for the API using Zend's rest controller library.

Here's a good tutorial on it: http://www.techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework.  You're basically using the same file structure as any zend app.

Then I'd have a completely separate zend app for your 3rd party.

If you're keeping them on the same server, you just put them in separate directories.

```
3rdpartyapp /
    application/
    public/
    library/
    ...

api /
    application/
    public/
    library/
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, definitely agree with this - keep them seperate. Not least because you may want to have other clients later on in time.

Comment: What would be the disadvantages if I have the whole thing organized as different modules? For example one module called api and other necessary modules that would connect to the single 'model' through the 'api' module. Would it not be easy then to manage and deploy the application as a single project?

Comment: If you plan on adding more third party applications, it might be easier to keep them separate so you can put them on different servers for better performance.  Also, if you're third party apps have different logins, it can be tricky when using modules, but not impossible. Then again, if you're 3rd party apps are using all the same libraries, modules would make sense.  It just depends on what you're going for.

Comment: Thanks a lot liz! Keeping the api as a separate project would make things easy and robust in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

TRy the ZoHo here https://www.zoho.com/general/blog/announcing-the-zoho-projects-api.html